# C# Apache Atlas API POST issue

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am writing some C# code to submit type definitions through a POST request to Apache Atlas (v2) and I am getting the following response:

"error":"Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.atlas.model.typedef.AtlasTypesDef` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor\/factory method to deserialize from String value (...

I have been able to submit GET requests successfully but not the POST as shown above.

The JSON (jsonText) looks like:

```
{
"entityDefs": [
  {
    "attributeDefs": [
      {
        "cardinality": "SINGLE",
        "description": "Administration Information",
        "isIndexable": false,
        "isOptional": true,
        "isUnique": false,
        "name": "Administration_Information"
      }
    ],
    "category": "ENTITY",
    "description": "RVCT Document",
    "guid": "dcebca9d-ea3f-42f2-a3d3-bd3e8cd785d8",
    "name": "SOME-TYPE-NAME",
    "typeVersion": "1.0"
  }
]
}
```

The C# code looks like:

```
var t = m_Client.PostAsync("/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs", jsonText);
```

m_Client is an instance of "HttpClient" and successfully reach the API services.  Upon inspection of the returned response I get the error previously shown.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue by not passing the jsonText but an object that gets serialized and after that I started to see issues that make sense and I can resolve.

I am good now.